# Tab Control in Winforms take time to load different tabs

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm not good with customization of controls. However in my application I started using a customized tab. My customized tab didn't work. So I went on with using [KRBTabControl](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38014/KRBTabControl). In my application I have used panels which are further placed in the individual tabs named **Home,Reports,Settings**. Everything works fine. But the issue that I face is that there is a delay in loading the controls when I click on various tabs. The controls placed inside the tab doesnt load properly.

Ex. If from Home I click to Settings. All the controls such as labels and button take a second to load. Which just seem awkward. I also tried double buffering the Form but still there is a delay. Is there a way using which I can make all the controls visible at the same time as soon as a new tab is clicked.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Code will be helpful. Are you creating the controls once or each time the form shows up you dynamically create them?

Comment: Your link isn't useful.  You do get to deal with the common issue with copying code from Codeproject.com, now you have two problems.  Pretty unlikely you actually have a "loading problem", more likely that you crammed the tab pages with way too many controls.  Getting them all painted takes time.

Comment: @etaiso I have just placed the controls over the panel and the panel is inside a tabpage of the control. Im not creating dynamically.

Comment: @HansPassant exactly i also think the same. But all those controls are mandatory. And i do believe that painting all of them is taking time. So is there anything I can do with them. Is there a workaround or code to make the controls visible at a faster pace. I do not want to change the tab control. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Vikneshwar I have this advice for you : **Don't use customized controls in CodeProject or any where user can post his code**, the sample code in such places is **good for learning** but you should not use them in your project, they're not well tested in all aspects. I've also tried using a customized `Ribbon` there and I found many problems with it, the author is very good to write it but it's not enough to use in a professional project. I'm pretty sure that your problem is caused by the `customized TabControl` which no one can feel easy to jump in and and debug for you. You're stuck with it.

Comment: @KingKing, thats a great advice. But at this point of time is there any other method(apart from changing the tab control) to paint or show the controls in a less amount of time.